# Iterative naming for a list created in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rename, naming

i wrote a loop:

```
for(a in 1:100){

   Code 

   list <- list("test1"=test1,"test2"=test2)
   save(list, file = paste(paste("test",a,sep="_"),".RData",sep=""))
  }
```

The iterative naming of the saved file works well, but I have not figured out a way to do this the list. The Problem is, that if I load the file into R the objects are both called list and thus I have a problem.

I have tried `mv(from = "list" , to = paste(paste("test",a,sep="_"))` but it does not work.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a tricky point, since `save(eval(parse(text=paste0("list", a))), file = paste("test",a,".RData",sep=""))` is not working for some reason, your best bet IMO would be to save one file only - which might be more convenient any way, and access the names of the objects in the list of lists:

```
test1 <- 1
test2 <- 2
mylist <- list()
for(a in 1:100){
  #assign(paste0("list",a), list("test1"=test1,"test2"=test2), environment())
  mylist[[a]] <- list("test1"=test1,"test2"=test2)
}
save(mylist, file = "mylist.RData")
```

Comment: The problem is that if I want to load the 100 Rdata files into R, the objects are all called "list".

Comment: With something like `load("test1.RData")`

Comment: Does not work because the save command does not take `paste0("list",a)`. I will try to solve it.